# Execute 2 headers at the same time

Tags: php, html, header

Anyone please help me, I am beginner of PHP programming, I have a problem on my code, I use header function to open the URL, I want to execute this 2 header at the same time, but the first header didnt work (the telegram message didn't send), but if I comment the 2nd header, the message delivered successfully.

The first header is to send data to telegram, after the message deliver to telegram user, I want to redirect to `index.php`

Here is my code :

```
/* the message didnt sent */

header('location: https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=123456789&text=THANKYOU);

header('location:index.php');

/* the message sent */

header('location: https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=123456789&text=THANKYOU);

//header('location:index.php');
```

Is there a way to do this kind of proses ?  first i want to send message to telegram user and after the message sent successfully, i want to redirect to `index.php` page.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong. Using `header('Location: ')` sends a user to another webpage, so by stacking them, the browser will only successfully redirect to the last one. What you probably want, is to call those pages server side, then redirect the user later:

```
$result = file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=123456789&text=THANKYOU');

header('location:index.php');
```

Comment: Hi Enstage, thank you for answering, yes i want to call those pages and at the end will show the last page (index.php) .. i have tried with your code, but its not working on me... any other way could help plz?